# Button.setText not working

Tags: android, button

really Basic question but i can't get the Point.

I have a Button with an onclicklistener and following style:

```
<style name="dialog_button_scale">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/dialog_button_scale_width</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_toLeftOf">@id/dialog_button_sort</item>
    <item name="android:text">medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">imagebtnPerRow</item>
```

for testing i simple tried:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myActivity);
    Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_scale);
    myBtn.setText("large");
    myBtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
}
```

But nothing changes... Any suggestions?

**Upgrade** Please, before Upvoting an answere:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_button_scale"
            style="@style/dialog_button_scale" />
```

Both names are the same, but one for style and one for id..

Sorry for confusing you guys..

**Update2** in my OnClick method i Change the text for example from medium to large and later i get the Text from the button and it is large but the UI isn't updating!

Answer (score 2):

In Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_scale); You are getting the style name instead of the Button @id of the xml layout.

Comment: No, they are both the same. But one is R.style the other one is R.id checked it. Can't be the Problem..

Comment: Would have been better placed as a comment. Because like michael said it would throw a NPE. Now some people could think that this is solving my problem... Don't get me wrong

Comment: Sorry, you are right, who can change it to be a comment? I am looking for a better solution but it doesn't make sense until now

Comment: @Gzuz07 Don't know ;/. Yeah it's a strange Thing.. even if i remove the style completely and do all in layout_XML. Same issue. When i remove the text of the style for the button. The Button stays empty even if i set a text to it. I really don't know what is going on here

Comment: myBtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); is not working for me, try using myBtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); instead and define the color black on values/color.xml

Comment: From your update 2 I think the text is invisible by default (Maybe for the theme you are using), so check setting the textColor in your xml to black instead of setting it in the Activity

Comment: @Gzuz07 I will try! If i set a Color which he doesn't know. Shouldn't then the Button be empty? Instead of leaving the old text?